# Adding complicated PHP file into joomla article

Tags: joomla2.5

i created order form in php (if the php file is alone its working, i tested it on my apache server.. its using sessions and a lot of if statements.) I thought i will install DirectPHP and just insert `<?php tags..` but it dont work.. only really strange so i installed Jumi plugin and if i upload my php file to / directory on joomla server and into article paste `{jumi [/test.php]}`

**test.php**

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

in article it writes

```
The file /test.php does not exist or is not readable!
```

i set attributes to 777 so its not about permissions.. what can i do ? thank you.

edit: I tried DirectPHP with `<?php include("./phpfile.php") ?>` ----------------------------------------------

and i found that there are two php constructs which does not work.. first is multidimensional array like that

```
$doprava = [
    array("nazev" => "Přepravní firma po ČR", "cena" => 125),
    array("nazev" => "Česká pošta - Balík do ruky", "cena" => 120),
    array("nazev" => "Česká pošta - Balík na poštu", "cena" => 115),
];
```

or `$abc = [array()];` (both does not work --> it returns internal 500 error)

and second is goto

```
goto html;
html:
```

maybe i can workaround goto (i dont know how for now, but **why does not work array** ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want show a php file.
I think DirectPHP is very good.
you can do it link this:

`<?php include("./phpfilename.php");?> (note:./ joomla root)`

goog luck!

Comment: i find there are two php constructs that does not work, i edited question. (first is multidimensional array and second is goto)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could save yourself a ton of problems and just us a form component like RS Forms or Chronoforms. Chronoforms would probably be very good for what you want because it allows you a high level of customization. We've built very complex order forms in Chronoforms many times.

Comment: Thank you but you know.. im using joomla very little and i dont like it :-) so when i have written php file its hard for me to just use some plugin which i cant be sure it will work, please look at my edited question.

Comment: Ok, you don't have to use those extensions, but both are very mature and work well and would likely make your task much easier. As for your 500 error, it's probably the version of PHP you are using. If you are using any version older than 5.4 then you cant use square [] brackets when constructing your arrays, you must use parentheses ().

Comment: Same thing with your goto error, that is only available in PHP 5.3.x or newer. What version of PHP are you using?